# Google Analytics tracker

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an application, in which I set a tracker. I use `tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();` and `tracker.startNewSession("<UA number", this);` in`onCreate()` in every activity. What I'm interested in - is it efficient to start new session in every separate activity or I can do that in my custom activity manager? In the second case I'm not actually sure where to stop the session? Currently I do this in every activity in onDestroy().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry you are doing fine.

If you have a lot of activities you can make a parent activity which handles the tracking like the [example here](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/tracking/mobile/android/v1/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/TrackedActivity.java?r=2).

Remember to track a page view in `onResume()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Anyway, I have a custom activity group and activity states are mixed up as for me... What are the consequences of NOT not stopping the session of the tracker (`tracker.stopSession();`) ?

Comment: And what is the difference between tracker.start() and tracker.startNewSession() ?

Comment: I think by default, the session times-out in 30 minutes (at least the web tracker session lasts for that duration), it should be lesser for mobiles. It isn't documented so I can't say for sure. ; Oh and the difference is that start() is deprecated.

Comment: 30 minutes is quite long. So, I assume stopping the tracker saves the battery and is recommended behaviour?

Comment: I don't think the tracker takes that much of battery, and yes, stopping the tracker is always recommended. Bundle your tracker dispatches with any other HTTP requests made by your application to save some battery.